issue after delete firebase plugin in android studio
After I delete these, the project won't run
its error
Configuration cache state could not be cached: field elements of org.gradle.configurationcache.serialization.codecs.ResolutionBackedFileCollectionSpec bean found in field compileTimeDependencies of task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsTask: error writing value of type 'java.util.ArrayList'

Could not find play-services-measurement-sdk-api-20.1.2.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:20.1.2).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-measurement-sdk-api/20.1.2/play-services-measurement-sdk-api-20.1.2.aar

 implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.2"))
 implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
 implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")

id("com.google.gms.google-services")
id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") 


id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.2" apply false
id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") version "3.0.1" apply false 

google-services.json

I use Google AdMob, does it interfere with Firebase?
